# Asp.Net MVC - View -> Create 2 objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-3.5, view

First of all, I'm really new to the MVC Asp.Net ideology.

I would like to know how can I create two objects (model) into one view ?

because if I look at the view header it's inherit from one model :

\<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

So, if, for example, I want to create in the same view (Aspx page) an MyObjectA and an object MyObjectB, what's the best way to handle that ?

I hope I've been clear ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a model object `Person` and another lets say `Comment` and then in the same view you would like to display a persons details and comments added to that person you may want to create an intermediate object sometimes referred to as a 'data transfer object' or 'view object'. So, i create a simple class:

```
public class PersonDetailDTO
{
    public Person PersonDetail {get; set;}
    public IList<Comment> Comments {get; set;}
}
```

.. now i can return the result of my action as type `PersonDetailDTO` instead of say `Person`. Then the view is strongly typed to `PersonDetailDTO` also, making it easy for me to access the PersonDetail data and Comments collection.

For example, i use a view object like this for one of my partial views:

```
        public class AnnouncementsPartialViewData
        {
            public IList<Announcement> Announcements { get; set; }
            public object MonthlyPlannerRouteVals { get; set; }
            public object PreSchoolRouteVals { get; set; }
            public object ElementaryRouteVals { get; set; }
        }
```

.. and the partial view header looks like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<KsisOnline.Web.Controllers.HomeController.IndexViewData.AnnouncementsPartialViewData>" %>
```

.. and so i can access the typed data from that view class in the view easily like so:

```
<% if (Model.Announcements.Count == 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

If by 'creating' you mean 'passing' two objects from a controller to a view, you should create a new class that would contain the two objects and pass it from the controller to the view:

```
public class MyModel
{
  public MyObjectA ObjectA { get; set; }
  public MyObjectB ObjectB { get; set; }
}
```

The View definition would then look like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyModel>" %>
```

In the controller, you would create the object like

```
...(in controller action)
return new MyModel { ObjectA = new MyObjectA(), ObjectB = new MyObjectB() };
```

From the view, you would access the objects like

```
var myObjectA = Model.ObjectA;
```